# How do I create single page application using a navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm aiming to create a single page application that works with a navbar. It is for a music review site, so the navbar will have 'Pop', 'HipHop' and 'Jazz'. I have a separate html page for each of these music genres, but instead I want to just have one big html page.

I have Javascript code that can make this work, but I'm not sure how to edit the contents of my navbar to allow this to happen.

This is my javascript file and nav bar as follows:

I would really appreciate any help

```
    pages: [],
    show: new Event('show'),
    init: function(){
        app.pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
        app.pages.forEach((pg)=>{
            pg.addEventListener('show', app.pageShown);
        })

        document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((link)=>{
            link.addEventListener('click', app.nav);
        })
        history.replaceState({}, 'Home', '#home');
        window.addEventListener('popstate', app.poppin);
    },
    nav: function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        let currentPage = ev.target.getAttribute('data-target');
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add('active');
        console.log(currentPage)
        history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
        document.getElementById(currentPage).dispatchEvent(app.show);
    },
    pageShown: function(ev){
        console.log('Page', ev.target.id, 'just shown');
        let h1 = ev.target.querySelector('h1');
        h1.classList.add('big')
        setTimeout((h)=>{
            h.classList.remove('big');
        }, 1200, h1);
    },
    poppin: function(ev){
        console.log(location.hash, 'popstate event');
        let hash = location.hash.replace('#' ,'');
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(hash).classList.add('active');
        console.log(hash)
        //history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
        document.getElementById(hash).dispatchEvent(app.show);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.init);

NAVBAR: 

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="statichtmlpage.html">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="pop.html">pop</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="hiphop.html">hiphop</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="jazz.html">jazz</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Absolute trash</a>
```

Comment: Just have a click event on each nav item that adds an active class for your page divs according to the name, changing them from display: none to display: block;

Comment: would you mind sharing some code, if thats alright?

Comment: Why not just leverage an easy framework like angular or a library like react? That way it's super easy to spin up, and if you decided to grow it you're not reinventing the wheel every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got most of this from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp
I believe this is close to what you are asking for. Let me know if this solves your problem.
One framework that I would look into is VueJS (https://vuejs.org/). You will be able to accomplish the same outcome with additional features that you could use to enhance your app. If you are interested in server side rendering then I would look into NuxtJS (https://nuxtjs.org/guide).

```js
function transition(genreName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(genreName).style.display = "block";
  return tablinks
}

function openTab(evt, genreName) {
  transition(genreName)
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function tabLink(genreName) {
  var tablinks = transition(genreName)
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    if (tablinks[i].innerHTML == genreName) {
      tablinks[i].className += " active"
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#Pop {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Pop')">Pop</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'HipHop')">HipHop</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Jazz')">Jazz</button>
</div>

<div id="Pop" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Pop</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rhoncus ut massa et ullamcorper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque tempor odio sit amet aliquam iaculis.</p>
  <p>If you are feeling Jazzy click <a href="#!" onclick="tabLink('Jazz')">HERE</a></p>
</div>

<div id="HipHop" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>HipHop</h3>
  <p>Sed eu efficitur lorem. Pellentesque varius nulla nec lectus consectetur ullamcorper. In at urna orci. Sed ut malesuada elit, vel tempor leo.</p>
</div>

<div id="Jazz" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Jazz</h3>
  <p>Fusce arcu magna, mollis eu cursus ut, mollis sit amet quam. Aenean mattis turpis vitae iaculis venenatis. Cras tempus gravida quam in malesuada.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: If you were to have the first tab as 'Home', how would you edit the code to make sure that home is already loaded when the page loads, instead of having a white screen and then having to click on Home to load its contents.

Comment: The #Pop CSS is what is making the Pop tab stay open when you first go to the page. Just copy the Pop portion of the html and replace the text with the home text. Change the id in the Home html to Home and change the #Pop in the CSS to #Home. Make sure to remove the active class from the button html and add it to the new Home button that you will need to add. Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One other problem I had was, how do you maintain the single page application with links? Right now, my website has about three links on each page that leads to a different html page. How do I fix this so that when one of these links are clicked it works in a similar way as you described in your earlier answer so that it doesn't go to a separate html page?

Comment: I updated my answer. In the first tab you will now see a link. You will need to insert the onclick function that I created. I created a couple of new functions. The transition function just holds all of the code that is being re-used in the other two functions. I created the tabLink() function so that when you click on a "link" it will darken the button like it would when you normally just click on the button itself. Let me know if this helps. You should be able to test this by running the code snippet above.

Comment: How do you carry out the same idea but if you're using list items in an unordered list. If each list item is a song in that list, how do I edit it so that when one of them is clicked, it goes to the relevant page of that song, but it shouldn't have the song name as an element in the navbar.